# Install 2 versions of Ubuntu on same hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I'm using ubuntu on dual-boot with windows.
I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a separate partition, After installing Windows 10.
ubuntu is my default OS, but I had an issue so I can't log in now.
as a part of the solution, I must get Windows off of the machine, but keep ubuntu.

I have 1000 GB on The HARD-DRIVE: 300 for Windows 10 and 700 for ubuntu (wich I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04).
the issue now I want to remove windows and replace it with ubuntu 16.04 without touching the 700 GB partition (old ubuntu partition). to eventually have Ubuntu 16.04 appear alongside Ubuntu 18.04 when I boot my computer.

When I tried that with a Live CD (ubuntu 16.04)  it gave me the following 3 options:

1. Delete 18.04 and install 16.04 in its place
2. Delete all partitions and install Ubuntu 16.04
3. Something Else

I'm looking forward to your advice, to do it the perfect way, should i worry about compatibility between 2 different ubuntu versions ? what about Grub ? thank you.

Comment: I love dual-booting (and selecting which I use via grub).  I always use 'try ubuntu', then partition my drive as I want, then install using 'something else' telling the system which partition is for what & let it install. I recently upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS, which was a minor pain in grub, as my 'test' system (same machine) was 18.04 LTS too, but it's since been bumped to 18.10.  No having multiple versions won't interfere with each other, but I have a /home partition for each (I gave up sharing $HOME due to hassles if versions differed too much...)

Comment: The last installed will 'own' your grub; however you can usually tell 'grub' not to install allowing it to remain 'owned' by a prior install (but the newer install won't show until you boot the older system & tell it to 'update-grub' etc...)  I don't think there is a 'perfect' way sorry; i'm just giving some of what works for me :)

Comment: Thanks, so as I understood, I have to select `Something Else` then partition the drive witch is already partitioned ( 700 GB for ubuntu 18.04 and 300 GB for windows ) the issue is replacing that 300 GB with ubuntu 16.04 , Any advice on that?

Comment: Yes you could use 'something else' & partition the drive that way.  I find `gparted` easier to use, which is why I said I 'try ubuntu' & partition (using my preferred `gparted`) then do install & select 'something else' pointing to the partition i want to use.  I do it this way as it suits me. As for the 300gb, I'd just delete the 'unwanted' partition(s), and create the partitions you want to use for your new 16.04. If you partition-table is 'gpt' you've no issues; however if it's old 'mbr' don't forget only four primary partitions are allowed (so create a  extended and subdivide that...)

Comment: what do you mean by old mbr? why four partitions ? I only need 2. and for Grub I think I have to choose `not install` then update it later.

Comment: the type of partition table used on your drive; 'gpt' allows drives greater than 2tb & many partitions; the old dos/mbr/(it has a number of names) allows only 4 primary partitions, extended counts as a primary (but can be subdivided into secondary partitions).  You can ignore that warning; unless if you delete one partition, and then get an error creating the second partition (in it's place).  If this error occurs, your "partition-table" is not GPT & has limits... This limit is related to the partition-table & the same on Ubuntu as with Windows.

Comment: Ok thank u , I think I have a new generation laptop so I hope that `partition-table`is GPT. IF NOT THAT WILL BE more complicated.
Anyway, what do you think about grub ? how to deal with that to prevent any bug then ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'bug' (in relation to grub); but I'd just install [Ubuntu] & let grub install.  Grub is easy to fix (or change ownership of MBR (master boot record; of first 512bytes of hdd/sdd).   If you are using UEFI I'm not the person to advise (I usually disable it; however if it's enabled; don't touch it or you risk having your existing Ubuntu not boot until it's returned to current setup). If you install another Ubuntu; it should detect your current setup & just install itself (detecting the other Ubuntu too & adding both to grub). Lots of fix-grub answers are on this site

Comment: can u please mention what partitions i have to delete on `Something Else` option ? I'm not experienced to use Gparted, there are like 5 or 6 partitions ...should I delete only NTFS and keep the others ? any image ... any Url , any explanation can help please don't hesitate if u can help. thank u

Comment: I have no idea what partitioning you have; as its influenced by drive; brand, history etc.   I also prefer terminal to gui (I'm guessing you don't). As example (example only) the command `mount |grep sda` lists "sda1 on / type ext4" meaning it's my root drive; and "sda3 on /home ext4" meaning it's where my data goes. (you could also use `sudo fdisk -l |grep sda`).  A gui tool is `gnome-disks` which calls sda1 "partition 1", also reports sda3 as "partition 3", and sda2 is swap. Take note of what yours are & DO NOT format/use them as they're used. NTFS will be windoze.

Comment: I usually write down (recycled envelope etc) what partitions are what (a map of my drive), highlighting what I want to keep (one color) & what to delete (different color) to ensure it's correct. I usually use a different command or method to ensure what I wrote down was correct (eg. you could use `gparted` or I listed three ways last comment)   As you want to kill windoze, you could boot it & do the same there (ie. what partitions windoze uses; those are what you want to kill; does it match up?), but it's up to you.

Comment: yeah, I want do that to be sure, and to prevent problems after installing the new system. seriously I'm lost a lill bit, I don't know what to do maybe the good Idea is killing windows with the windows liveDVD and then go to install ubuntu, or just try ubuntu with live dvd then Gparted to remove unwanted partitions . and reboot to install it and maybe (with some chance) I'll get another options to install like : install ubuntu 16.04 alongside ubuntu 18.04 without dealing with `Something Else` option

Comment: I wouldn't use windows to kill windows; most OSes tend to protect themselves (or something they recognize as itself). Ubuntu or any GNU/Linux won't baby user(s) as much (thus allows it), but I'd do the deleting in the Ubuntu you want to keep (it'll have your / & /home mounted, thus won't let you touch those; protecting itself)...  Once you delete the windows; boot your Ubuntu install media; it may offer a "install alongside other-Ubuntu" (or however it presents it - ie. what you want!).  If you're not sure; just don't do it (at least not until you're comfortable)...

Comment: I'm just avoiding to deal with partitioning cause I risk to do it wrong, u know it doesn't lookso friendly , and I don't think I have the choice to do it or not , I have to kill windows to use ubuntu because I can't log in the other partition for another story, I don't think it was my fault but that's happen u know OS like that usually updates are not stables causes some problems, but I'm sure I'll fix it I can never give up, the problem is just time witch i don't have enough for now, so it's the only thing I can do to use ubuntu on that lap. then maybe few weeks later I'll have much time

Comment: much time specially to learn ( why not everything ) about partitioning and dual triple boot. I'm very interested in that basics ...  and thank you for all your answers really thank you